# Google Sheets script that will reference a column of doc IDs and run a process for each document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I manage 70 different sheets, each of which requires a simple update (add row, enter date) to be input once per week. The following script functions well for updating ONE document. Now I need a script that can reference all 70 documents, who's IDs are kept in a column on a separate sheet. I'm brand new to scripting. Please help me learn!

```
function addNewRow() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID OF THE ONE DOC THAT RECEIVES UPDATES");
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Role 1");
sheet.insertRowBefore(19);
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()+1).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
sheet.getRange(19,1).setValue(today); sheet.getRange(19,8).setValue(today); 
sheet.getRange(19,13).setValue(today); 

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. There are several ways to make change over multiple spreadsheets... The script will have to open each of the spreadsheet. Are all the spreadsheets in the same folder? Does the spreadsheets have a standard file name? Do you have a list of all the spreadsheets ids or URLs? Also, please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Thank you! The spreadsheets are all in their own folders, which are all in one folder. Google sheets file names are standardized right up until the ID. I have a list of all of the IDs in a separate spreadsheet. I have been searching on this topic, but my understanding of how the script I wrote above can be executed from a list in another spreadsheet is limited. The syntax when coupling two processes (one that looks at a list of IDs, one that performs an action on the related doc) is still mysterious to me.

Comment: Please read [Reading data](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/#reading_data). If you need further help please show what you have tried to read the IDs and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].